# How can I open an excel viewer file using c++?

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

main(){

    int i, k=0;
    //while(1){

    char prova[9]="20:00:00";
    char timeStr [9];
    _strtime( timeStr );
    //printf( "The current time is %s \n", timeStr);

    for(i=0;i<9;i++){
    if(prova[i]!=timeStr[i])
        k=1;
    }

   if(k=1){

    system("C:\>tskill xlview");
    system("C:\>start "" Programas\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\xlview.exe" "c:\teste.xls");
   }
   //main();
}
```

/*I intend to make a program that closes and then opens an excel viewer file, everyday at a certain hour. I know how to execute a shell command but the path's I´m using are not working*/

Comment: English sentences start with uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "C:>start" use "start" or the full path to the program file. "C:>" is the command prompt.